# Chart Name in Excel 2016

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the name of a chart in excel 2016, however the layout tab isn't displayed on the ribbon under chart tools. Does anyone know how to add it or find an alternative way of finding the chart name?

Comment: What do you mean by chart name? pie, line, scatter? are these?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you select the chart, it's now to the left of the formula bar.

Answer (score 10):

In Excel 2016, the old ribbon tab *Layout* no longer appears when you select a chart. In previous versions of Excel, this tab contained the properties box that you could use to name or rename a chart.

You can rename a chart in two ways in Excel 2016. When you select the chart, the chart's name appears in the Name box, which is located to the left of the formula bar, as noted in previous answer. The default name will be something like *Chart 2*. By selecting *Chart 2* in the name box, and typing over it with your new name, you are renaming the chart. After you type in your new name, press the ENTER key to complete the process.

Somewhat confusingly, chart names *do not* appear in the dropdown list of the name box. Once you've named a chart, the only way to immediately see the chart's name again is to click into it to select it. The chart name will then appear in the name box. And you can't use the name box to navigate directly to a chart, as you can with a range or a table.

There's another, and more arcane method of changing the name. Select the chart, and go to the *Format* tab under *Chart Tools* in the ribbon. On the right side of the Format ribbon, click *Selection Pane*. This pops out a menu bar on the right side of the worksheet. This bar lists all the charts on the current sheet. A slow double-click opens the chart name in a textbox, and you can rename it. Pressing ENTER or clicking outside the textbox completes the process.

[image]

Comment: This is a solid answer and I thought it deserved an image showing the two methods you described so I added one.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2016: 
Click chart, then click on Name box then rename the chart and press Enter